# Polymer Page with different app-header on home page

Tags: polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

i'm trying to make difference between home page and other page in polymer 2.0

1. Home page = With big header and condensed
2. Other Page = just as usual app-header with small header on the top

what i try to do is using dom-if, i create dom-if with 2 kind of app-header

```js
_isHome(page) {
  return page === "view1";
}
```

```css
app-header#homeHeader {
  color: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  --app-header-background-front-layer: {
    background-image: url(../images/Digital-Signage-Slider3a.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  ;
}

app-header#defaultHeader {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: var(--app-primary-color);
}
```

```html
<app-header-layout>
  <template is="dom-if" if="[[_isHome(page)]]">
    <app-header id="homeHeader" slot="header" condenses reveals effects="parallax-background" style="height: 500px">
      <app-toolbar>
        <div main-title>My App</div>
        <paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>
  </template>

  <template is="dom-if" if="[[!_isHome(page)]]">
    <app-header id="defaultHeader" slot="header" condenses reveals effects="material">
      <app-toolbar>
        <div main-title>My App</div>
          <paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>
  </template>

  <iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="view404" role="main">
    <my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>
    <my-view2 name="view2"></my-view2>
    <my-view3 name="view3"></my-view3>
    <my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
  </iron-pages>
</app-header-layout>
```

and guess what? it worked, but with some space after it, but the space is gone after refreshed hmm..

## Home Page with large image condensed header

[image: The home page with large image condensed header]

## After click on the 2nd page

[image: After click on the 2nd page]

## After refreshed

[image: After refreshed]

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revised Solution**

I had another go at this because on an app I started yesterday. I think I've a simplier solution, with only one `app-header` and one `app-toolbar`.

First I replace the `app-header#...` styles with these:

```
.main-title {
  color: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  --app-header-background-front-layer: {
    background-image: url(../images/Digital-Signage-Slider3a.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  ;
}

.condensed-title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: var(--app-primary-color);
}
```

The header and toolbar are now

```
<app-header-layout id="header" has-scrolling-region>

  <app-header class$=[[_getHeaderClass(page)]] slot="header" fixed effects="waterfall">

    <app-toolbar>
      <template is="dom-if" if=[[_isHome(page)]]>
        <div main-title>My App 1</div>
      </template>
      <template is="dom-if" if=[[!_isHome(page)]]>
        <div condensed-title>My App 2 & 3</div>
      </template>
      <paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
    </app-toolbar>

  </app-header>
  ...
```

The function called to set `app-header`'s class is

```
_getHeaderClass(page) {
  return (page === "view1") ? 'main-title' : 'condensed-title';
}
```

Note that you must still call `this.$.header.notifyResize()` in `_routePageChanged(page)`.

I've put up a gist of the complete file at [`my-app-revised.html`](https://gist.github.com/johnthad/ea8c26bde89d2333843507e9859836c3).

----- former solution -----

Call [`notifyResize()`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout/elements/app-header-layout#method-notifyResize) on the `app-header-layout`.

If you look at the `polymer-starter-kit`, give the `app-header-layout` an `id`, like `id="header"`:

```
<app-header-layout id="header" has-scrolling-region>
```

Then call `this.$.header.notifyResize()` in `_routePageChanged(page)`:

```
_routePageChanged(page) {
  // If no page was found in the route data, page will be an empty stri.
  // Default to 'view1' in that case.
  this.page = page || 'view1';
  this.$.header.notifyResize();

  // Close a non-persistent drawer when the page & route are changed.
  if (!this.$.drawer.persistent) {
    this.$.drawer.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: waw, it works, but it moving up too far, now the content overlap the app-header, but after refreshed it go to it's position, i think there is something missing right? the content now 10px padding from the top page not from app-header, after refreshed it moved to 10px padding from app-header.

Comment: Let's see... Ah! I also added the property `has-scrolling-region` to `app-header-layout` (see my edit above) and removed `style="height: 500px"` from the first header b/c it's in the CSS. Does that work? Otherwise, I've not modified the PSK.

Comment: After removing an errant `<div>` I'd slipped in, I see what you're saying about pages 2 and 3. It feels kludgey, but `iron-pages > *:not(:first-child) { margin-top: 60px;}` works to force all but the first page (view1) lower. I'll put my `my-app.html` in a gist or someplace if that would help you.

Comment: Gist:  https://gist.github.com/johnthad/12a785ca2b068129398119f17fb8199a

Comment: yes it worked, but after refreshed it added some space between header and content, i think it is ok for temporary solution :)